# Android show different number on calling screen

Tags: android

I want to create an application where I open a calling intent with some number as below.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:999999999"));
startActivity(intent);
```

so it calls the number 999999999 and shows the number 999999999 in the calling screen, but is it possible in Android to show the number 888888888 but call 999999999?

Comment: I certainly would hope that it was not possible at all!

Comment: Just tried something on my device, and I couldn't get satisfying result for your issue (which is **good**, actually). I won't explain what I did though, for safety reason.